# Display WordPress Parent Categories Only?

Tags: categories

I have the following code on a custom wordpress page:

```
    <?php 
    $cat_array = array();
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => 10,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $cat_args=array('orderby' => 'none');
        $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'category', $cat_args);
        foreach($cats as $cat) {
          $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->term_id;
        }
      endwhile;
    }
    if ($cat_array) {
      foreach($cat_array as $cat) {
        $category = get_term_by('ID',$cat, 'category');
        echo '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($category, 'category')) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>'.'<br />';
      }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

It lists the categories in order of most recently updated category first. How do I adjust the code to get parent categories only?

## Example:

Basically, I would just like to display the top level category. For example:

Category - Subcategory - Sub Subcategory - Sub Sub Subcategory

Just Category.

Comment: When you say parent categories, you mean only the categories at the very top of the tree, right?

Comment: I believe so... Like when you create categories in WordPress, you can set a parent category for other categories... That's what I was referring to.

Comment: Well yes, but a category can have a parents and grandparents, etc, I'm trying to determine if you mean show the parents of the categories, or if you mean show only categories that don't have parents at all (as in they're at the top of the tree)...if you could clarify the original question, hopefully with an example, as to what specifically you'd like to show that would be outstanding.

Comment: Basically, I would just like to display the top level category. For example: Category - Subcategory - Sub Subcategory - Sub Sub Subcategory Just Category.

Comment: I got it figured out. Thank you so much for your time. I do appreciate it very much.

Comment: Please do not use answers for discussion. There are [comments](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) for that and you should be able to comment on own question and answers for it without reputation requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for. It's untested, I just whipped it up really quick right now, but the concept is there.

```
function my_get_highest_parent( $id ) {
    $cat = get_category( $id );
    $parent = $cat->parent;

    if( $parent == 0 ) 
        return $id;
    else
        my_get_highest_parent( $parent );
}
```